# Resizing a div and background with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the height of my header div and its background based on the height of the screen.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function getScreenSize() {
"use strict";
var h = window.innerHeight;

document.getElementById("header").style.height = h;
}
```

and then I used onload with the body tag.

```
<body onload="getScreenSize()">
```

Here's the full site on [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ms0n6a3s/) just in case.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you use CSS? `@media`... `%`, `vh`... you know...

Comment: `document.getElementById("header").style.height = h + 'px'`

Comment: Which window heights are you specifically targeting?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify units when setting styles with JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("header").style.height = h + 'px';  //added + 'px'
```

Comment: header height to window height? strange idea.

Comment: Oh *facepalms that stumped me for like 15 minutes, thanks.